# how to fix `error 'JSX' is not defined no-undef` after upgrade to typescript 4.4.2

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I have lots of error `error  'x' is not defined no-undef` after upgrade to typescript 4.4.2 from typescript 3.8.2. one of example is `error  'JSX' is not defined                no-undef` and I take a deeper look, most of is from `declarations.d.ts` how can I solve it?

```
"typescript": "4.4.2"
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.31.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.31.0",
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [typescript-eslint troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/docs/linting/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#i-get-errors-from-the-no-undef-rule-about-global-variables-not-being-defined-even-though-there-are-no-typescript-errors):

> We strongly recommend that you do not use the no-undef lint rule on TypeScript projects. The checks it provides are already provided by TypeScript without the need for configuration - TypeScript just does this significantly better.

In your `.eslintrc.js`, turn the rule off for TypeScript files:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {
    'no-shadow': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-shadow': ['error'],
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
      rules: {
        'no-undef': 'off',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### This worked for me in my .eslintrc.json

For eslintrc.js refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70546501/14853666)

```
 "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "rules": {
        "no-undef": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
```